# 2D Volumetric Lighting Methods?

Tags: effects, lighting, game-maker

Quick note, using GameMaker, doesn't matter though. I've been messing around with lighting for ages now and can never seem to think up an efficient method.

I did in fact accomplish Volumetric Lighting, although it slows down at 70 shadow casters and around 10~ lights. Which isn't entirely optimal, result: http://i.imgur.com/GMfhpNY.png

Now each "shadow" that gives the volumetric lighting effect is drawn pretty poorly. The shadow is drawn at a low alpha, moved back a few pixels, alpha increased, draw, repeat...

The shadow is a sprite and itself could be drawn 50 times... Slow...
So I was wondering if anyone had any better, more efficient methods than this.
Ideas? All I need is a way to draw the shadows to give a voluemtric effect, after
that I can do the rest. :)

Comment: Now I could make the lights static by rendering them to their own surfaces and save a LOT of FPS. Which I plan to do, however I'd still need a better way to draw the shadows! :)

Answer (score -1):

GameMaker:Studio 1.2 provides shaders, use them.

Comment: Easier said than done... I have no idea how to write shaders, especially for this. I'd need someone to do that for me...

Comment: There are examples on http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showforum=136 and even it's already done by somebody: http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=590030 - youtube demo here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsbECSpwtig

Comment: That's 2D lighting... not 2D *Volumetric* Lighting, HUGE difference.